# Does windows server 2012 place any special restrictions on cscript.exe or OLE DB provider?

Tags: vbscript, odbc, oledb, wsh

I have a simple script

```
Set Connection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Connection.Open("DSN=dsn; UID=userid; PWD=password")
queryString = "SELECT * FROM SSW_RECORD"
set RS = Connection.Execute(queryString)
Wscript.Echo("hello, world!")
If NOT(RS.EOF) or NOT(RS.BOF) Then
    Do While NOT(RS.EOF)
        Wscript.Echo(RS("SSW_ORDER_NO"))
    Loop
End If
```

It works on my machine (completely unmodified). However, when I try to deploy it to the production server, I get `test.vbs(2, 1) Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers: Unable to open connection to server.`
Also, not sure if I should ask this on SuperUser instead.

Comment: Not for `CScript`. Try it with the 32 bit `CScript` at `C:\windows\SysWoW64\Cscript` to rule out 32/64 bit issues.

Comment: Yep, I am using the 32 bit cscript.

Answer (score 0):

```
Connection.Open("DSN=dsn; UID=userid; PWD=password")
```

Looks like you aren't providing a connection string that it can use.  I'm assuming it defaults to localhost on your machine where you have a server hosted.

Might be why it isn't working on another machine.